# How to update an old object and pass the new object in a form?

Tags: jsf

I'm practicing CRUD in jsf, I hit a problem on the  "Update" concept, this is the basic flow of my application for updating existing data;

Assuming: Student first name should be changed.

1. Search for an existing student
2. The results are displayed on a h:dataTable with a "view" link beside it
3. Clicking the "view" link will direct you into a another page wherein the details of the student is viewed, on the bottom of the form a "edit" button is displayed
4. Clicking the "edit" button, all the student fields will be changed from h:outputText to h:insertText. A "save" button would also be displayed.
5. Choose a field/s to edit
6. Click "save" button
7. The problem lies in this step, the student object that was supposedly be updated was not updated at all. It seems that the changes made were not really "save". How can I efficiently passed down the new values so that I can update the student object?

Search page

```
<h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Action</f:facet>
        <h:link value="View" outcome="/view/view-student.xhtml">
        <f:param value="#{studentSearch.studentID}" name="studentID" />
        </h:link>
</h:column>
```

View student page

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="studentID" value="#{student}"
        converter="#{userConverter}"></f:viewParam>
</f:metadata>

<body>

    <h:form id="View_and_Edit_Form">
<h:outputLabel for="firstNameOutputText" value="First Name: "
            rendered="#{not student.editable}" />
        <h:outputText id="firstNameOutputText" value="#{student.firstName}"
            rendered="#{not student.editable}" />
        <h:outputLabel for="firstNameInputText" value="First Name: "
            rendered="#{student.editable}" />
        <h:inputText id="firstNameInputText" value="#{student.firstName}"
            rendered="#{student.editable}" />
        <br />

        <h:outputLabel for="lastNameOutputText" value="Last Name: "
            rendered="#{not student.editable}" />
        <h:outputText id="lastNameOutputText" value="#{student.lastName}"
            rendered="#{not student.editable}" />
        <h:outputLabel for="lastNameInputText" value="Last Name: "
            rendered="#{student.editable}" />
        <h:inputText id="lastNameInputText" value="#{student.lastName}"
            rendered="#{student.editable}" />
        <br />

        <h:commandButton value="Edit" action="#{student.setStudentEditable()}"
            rendered="#{not student.editable}">
            <f:param name="studentID" value="#{student.studentID}">  </f:param>
        </h:commandButton>

        <h:commandButton type="submit" value="Save"
            action="#{studentDAO.updateStudent()}"
            rendered="#{student.editable}">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{student}"
                target="#{studentDAO.student}" />
            <f:param name="studentID" value="#{student.studentID}"></f:param>
        </h:commandButton>
</h:form>

</body>
```

Student DAO

```
@ManagedBean(name = "studentDAO")
@ViewScoped
public class StudentDao implements Serializable{

Student student;
    List<Student> studentList;

    private Long studentIDSearch;
    private String firstNameSearch;
    private String lastNameSearch;

public String updateStudent() {

        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionfactory().openSession();

        System.out.println(this.student.getFirstName());

        try {
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.update(student);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Update Error");
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Running the application would result in displaying the student's old first name (from the updateStudent() method in student DAO class).

Additional info:

Student class itself uses @ViewScoped

Comment: update the form in your commandbutton using (update=":View_and_Edit_Form")

Comment: Hi, I can't see the "update" attribute using the CTRL + space

Comment: sorry, I thought it is a primefaces commandbutton and not h:commandbutton. In such case, use <f:ajax> inside the <h:commandbutton> and set your (render=":View_and_Edit_Form") attribute.

Comment: I tried using a primefaces commandButton and put the update="View_and_Edit_Form", but the passed object is "null" that is why I'm encountering this exception; java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: attempt to create saveOrUpdate event with null entity

Comment: I suggest you read a little bit about how to use ajax requests and events. It will help you develop your answer